# CryptDecodeObjectEx Bad Tag ERROR (0x8009310b)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, getlasterror

I have a .cer file. I can read it and write a buffer via ReadFile() function. 
Now I have buffer and datalen which I had.

And I use that buffer and len for calling CryptDecodeObjectEx() function like below line

```
if ( !CryptDecodeObjectEx( X509_ASN_ENCODING, 
                           X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, 
                           (BYTE* )pemPubKey, 
                           readLen, 
                           CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG, 
                           NULL, 
                           &publicKeyInfo, 
                           (DWORD *)&publicKeyInfoLen ) )
```

But when I run it through debug, I get 0x8009310B error code via GetLastError() func.

How can I fix it? 
Thanks for your advice.

Additional Information

- If I use X509_ANY_STRING instead of X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO; it works.
  But it does not fill my publicKeyInfo struct. Because of that I
  cannot get public key in it .
- I have a DER formatted certificate.

Comment: Did you bother to look up with that error code (0x8009310B) *means*? Probably the private key doesn't match the public key.

Comment: I think no. Because I just want to get public key in certificate. I mean it contains a public key yet. I just get it and send a new buffer and than I will use it in CryptImportPublicKeyInfo() function.

Comment: You did base64 decode pemPubKey? (CryptStringToBinary)

Comment: @Alex K. Im so sorry . I wrote wrong info but I have replaced it. My mistake was to say "I have a PEM formatted certificate" but I have a DER formatted certificate. Because of that I didnt use CryptStringToBinary() func.